# Are there power levels mentioned in Nanatsu no Taizai: Mokushiroku no Yonkishi?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the original Nanatsu no Taizai anime series, featuring the Nanatsu no Taizai members, they sometimes mentioned the fighters power levels, they were read by Hawk with a (magical?) device he had in the ear.  Nanatsu no Taizai: Mokushiroku no Yonkishi just started and they aired 2 episodes, featuring a very powerful Percival. I was wondering if Percival power level is mentioned in the manga or something.

Are there power levels mentioned in Nanatsu no Taizai: Mokushiroku no Yonkishi?

Comment: I don't think they ever go beyond "This person has an incredibly huge aura!", as of chapter 124. And I mean in general, not just with Percival.